# Regex non printable bytes

Tags: c++, regex, unicode, ascii

How can I get matched regex with non printable Unicode or ASCII bytes?

```
    char cData[1024] = { 0 };
    memcpy(cData, "\x00\x04\x02\x08\x00hello thats it", 19);

    std::regex r2e("([\\x00-\\x1F]){5}(.?)*", std::regex_constants::basic);
    if (std::regex_search((char*)cData, cData+19, r2e))
        printf("ok");
    else
        printf("nok");
```

My example is not working (printing "nok").

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: Printing "nok"! If I'm wright. First 5 bytes will be matched on first group, so "hello that's it" in other group?! (off course, if matchs it)

Comment: Did you definitely mean to use octal character literals? I initially thought not, but then I saw the `\010` and the fact that the other, 2-digit ones would be the same in hex (`\xnn`), so maybe you did.

Comment: How can I Ignore 5 first bytes? I have change my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. I was using the wrong 'regex_constants'.

Thanks for Mike for the help. But, after a lot of debug tryings, I have found one of them that works fine!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    char cData[1024] = "\x00\x04\x02\x08\x01Haaaaa";// { 0 };
    char cReg[] = "([\0-\x1F]{5})(.*)";
    int aux[sizeof(cReg)];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cReg); i++)
    {
        aux[i] = cReg[i];
    }
    std::match_results<char*> mc;
    std::initializer_list<int> list(aux, aux + 14);
    std::regex r2e(cReg,14, std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
    if (std::regex_match((char*)cData, cData+10, mc, r2e, std::regex_constants::match_default)) {
        for (auto it : mc)
            std::cout << it.str().c_str() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "NOK" << std::endl;
    }
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
std::regex r2e("[\x00-\x1F]\\{5\\}.*", 12, std::regex_constants::basic);
```

**Notes:**

1. You need to insert the literal characters in the `[ - ]` range.
2. `{` need to be escaped in basic regular expressions.
3. `(.?)*` has the same effect as `.*`.
4. You have to use this constructor which needs length of the string as another argument, because the `\x00` null char would end the string.

Comment: Sorry man, but this does not work too... '{5}' is to five repetitions.

Comment: regex_error(error_escape): The expression contained an invalid escaped character, or a trailing escape.

Comment: I'm using VC++. If use: std::regex r2e("[\x01-\x1F]{5}.*", 10, std::regex_constants::basic); Works fine! Note '\x01' but I need '\x00'.

Comment: No, '\x00' catch me "The expression contained an invalid escaped character, or a trailing escape."

Comment: That's odd. Try `\0`.